# In Reincarnated as a Slime, if Rimuru gave a last name would it be beneficial?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

Rimuru gave Veldora and himself a last name, but given all his power came from Veldora it wouldn't have had an impact. If he gave last names to others, such as Treyni and the driads, would it have been beneficial to them? Would it create a soul corridor and would it have granted them powers during the Harvest Festival?

Answer (score 1):

From what I read in the [wiki](https://tensura.fandom.com/wiki/Name), giving a last name establishes their position as equals and not as master and servant. It also gives them freedom to grow and use each others abilities freely.

> If he gave last names to others, such as Treyni and the driads, would
> it have been beneficial to them? Would it create a soul corridor and
> would it have granted them powers during the Harvest Festival?

I think it is beneficial to them as they can now use Rimuru's abilities(depending on the level of their magicules). It will create a soul corridor, Veldora as  an example. During the Harvest Festival, they would receive a powers/skill or upgrade of skill like Veldora's Investigator unique skill to Ultimate Skill.